# Dielectric field in a homogenous electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

I'm working through my workbook right now and currently am stuck on the chapter about dielectrics. The term $\vec{E}=\frac{3}{\epsilon_r +2}\vec{E_0}$ was introduced without a proper proof. Instead the book refers to an exercise in the problem set available at the end of the chapter. It basically consists of two parts:

> (1) An electric neutral sphere (radius R) consists of a sphere with homogeneous charge density $+\rho$ and another sphere with charge density $-\rho$. The spheres are displaced by $\vec{d}$ from one another.
>
> Show that for the overlapping area of those spheres the electric field is $$\vec{E}=-\frac{1}{3\epsilon_0}\vec{P}.$$
>
> (2) To get to the desired term $\vec{E}=\frac{3}{\epsilon_r +2}\vec{E_0}$ think about the following: If you put the dielectric sphere into the external electric field $E_0$ then, at first, there is the electric field $E_0$ within the sphere. This field then causes a polarization $P_0$, which creates another field $E_1$ within the sphere according to the term derived in (1). This field $E_1$ then causes another polarization $P_1$ and so forth...
>
> Show that the series $$\vec{E^{(N)}}=\sum_{n=0}^N\vec{E_n}$$ converges to the desired term $\vec{E}=\frac{3}{\epsilon_r +2}\vec{E_0}$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$.

I tried using my scant ability with GIMP to visualize the situation in (1) for myself.

[image]

I hope that's the correct interpretation of the problem.

But I have no idea how to approach this. At first I was thinking of looking at the initial situation (just an electric neutral sphere) which then would be displaced by the initial electric field and by using p=qd (dipole moment) I was trying to get an expression of the electric field in terms of the polarization but it was for naught.

Could anyone help me solve this? I hate reading on in the workbook without knowing how the term was derived.